# Installing isc-dhcp-server error

Tags: software-installation, wifi, apt, dhcp

I am following this [1] tutorial, and trying to install

```
sudo apt-get install hostapd isc-dhcp-server
```

according to this [2] step. I am getting the following error:

```
[FAIL] Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpd[....] check syslog for diagnostics. ...     failed!
 failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript isc-dhcp-server, action "start" failed.
```

What should I do?

[1] http://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview

[2] http://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software

EDIT:

tail /var/log/syslog

```
Wrote 0 leases to leases file.

No subnet declaration for wlan0 (192.168.0.115)
** Ignoging requests on wlan0. Please write a subnet declaration in your dhcpd.conf file for network segment to which interface wlan0 is attached. **

Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
```

In the dhcpd.conf file these are the only lines that are not commented:

```
ddns-update-style none;
option domain-name 'example.org';
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.42.10 192.168.42.50;
option broadcast-address 192.168.42.255;
option routers 192.168.42.1;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option domain-name "local";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your wifi is `192.168.0` but your dhcpd config is `192.168.42` - is that really the case? If so, you might want to fix the two to agree....

Comment: The address that is assigned to my Pi is 192.168.178.25  What ip addresses should I put in the different config files?